# Omega limit set and Stable manifold of a point

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems

I can not understand the difference between omega limit of a point and its stable manifold? Anybody can give me some example please?

Comment: This isn't really research-level and you may have better luck on http://math.stackexchange.com/ (as per the FAQ here), but FWIW you may perhaps gain some insight by sonsidering the example $f\colon \mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $f(x,y) = (2x, y/2)$, and using the definitions to work out the omega limit set and stable manifold of $(0,0)$.  Then try $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$.

Comment: As @Vaughn Climenhaga said, this question is not research level. But maybe a quick answer is that if $x$ is in the omega limit set of $p$, then $p$ is in the stable manifold of $x$ and vice versa.